# MYSQL and PHP insert with new id on every day

Tags: php, mysql

My web is for booking the Appointment of client to a lawyer
Where I want to give report based on first booking first appoint in ascending order based on date.

how can I insert the data to mysql so that on every new date new id will start

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can have a column i.e IdByDay. Everyday you will enter your date i.e month/day/year, No two dates are the same thus it will always be unique.

Comment: When new records are created, use an id that is a counter of all ids that day, so the first id for 1 Jul 2016 would be 20160701-01, the second would be 20160701-02.  The number before the dash is the date, the number after is a counter starting at 01 for the first appt of the day.  You can sort those by date and by counter of a specific day.